# STM32F4 ADC not working in Continous Mode

Tags: stm32f4discovery, stm32f4

i am using stm32 discovery board and using internal ADC in continuous conversion mode. in while(1) loop if i have only one statement to read ADC then the result is correct and i can see the analog value if i change the input. however, if i use any other statement along with ADC read, then the value is not updated.

here is the portion of the code. please share your knowledge.

```
while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
        raw = HAL_ADC_GetValue(&hadc1);
        voltage = raw / 4096 * 3.0;
        HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_13);
        HAL_Delay(500);
  }
```

Comment: Which value is not updated? And how do you know? (There is no output statement.)

Comment: raw is not updating and i see it in debug mode

Comment: Inspecting variables that are no used for anything can be misleading. The compiler might have optimized it away as it is not needed for anything. Better change the code. And please show the code that is not working. As it stands, your question is: "This code works, but the other code, that I'm not showing, doesn't work."